# Changing a single element of the widget style

Tags: java, css, gwt

How to change single element of the widget style in GWT. I would like to create new version of TextBox style, so that only the border color changed to red, for example.How to get to the style responsible for the TextBox?

I tried to create new style

```
.gwt-TextBox.invalid {
border-color: red;
}
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you [add class](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#addStyleName%28java.lang.String%29) `invalid` to your TextBox:

   ```
   textBox.addStyleName("invalid");
   ```
2. Use `CssResource` to associate your CSS file with GWT: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html#cssfiles

Comment: I fallow this guide http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/GettingStartedStyle but AddStyleDependentName(), or AddStyle do not work for me. I think that I do not need to associate my CSS file with GWT, because I use only one CSS file, which was generated by the GWT during my project inicialization.